# Matlab: Animating bouncing ball realistically (simulating Earth's conditions)

Tags: matlab, animation

I've followed [this tutorial](https://zerocrossraptor.wordpress.com/matlab-undercover/creating-simple-animation-in-matlab/) on how to animate bouncing ball with matlab. Everything works just fine except it does not follow one of my requirements, mainly:

> For given gravitational acceleration that is close to Earth's one (~10 m/s^2), the ball should *look like* real ball bouncing on Earth (maximum speed, acceleration...).

But with what I get is ball slowly moving up and down, with acceleration visible but definitely much too slow compared to real ball (youtube video at the end of tutorial).

From tutorial:

- [source code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58862230/MATLAB%20Undercover/MATLAB%20Undercover%2001%20-%20Simple%20Animation/Script01b.m)

Next step would be adding initial horizontal speed but still the same problem occurs.

How to make this animation faster -> more realistic?

@EDIT
I must add that getting it correctly for Earth is first step. By design this should be a proper approximation for any given gravitational acceleration and initial speed.

Comment: More realistic? The collisions in the example don't seem to be handled properly. It's neither a proper elastic nor inelastic collision. See the built-in example [`ballode`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ordinary-differential-equations.html?refresh=true#f1-669698) in Matlab for one way to do this. Also, the speed of what you see on the screen has nothing to do with wether or not the simulation is accurate or not. In fact the playback may not even occur in linear time unless you record a movie of it. If your goal is realtime simulation/animation of physics, that's a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons for the ball seems moving slow can be the initial position set in the script:

```
initpos=50;     %Ball's initial vertical position
```

the unit of measure of the initial position has to be considered be metre to be consistent with the definition of `g`

```
gravity=10;     %Gravity's acceleration
```

If you reduce the initial height of the ball you can see the ball "seems" moving faster but only because it has "less" space to travel while the size of the `figure` remains the same.

I've modified your script by removing (commenting) some lines of code that can slow down its execution as well as I've changed the initial position from `50` to `5` (to do this, I also had to reduce the size of the ball).

```
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Script01b - Bouncing Ball
%Creating Simple Animation in MATLAB
%MATLAB Undercover
%zerocrossraptor.wordpress.com
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%This script m-file creates an endless animation of bouncing balls.
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

%CodeStart-----------------------------------------------------------------
%Resetting MATLAB environment
    close all;
    clear all;
    clc;
%Declaring ball's initial condition
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Modified ball's initial position
% % %     initpos=50;     %Ball's initial vertical position
    initpos=5;     %Ball's initial vertical position
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
    initvel=0;      %Ball's initial vertical velocity
%Declaring environmental variable
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Modified ball's radius
% % %     r_ball=5;       %Ball's radius
    r_ball=0.25;       %Ball's radius
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
    gravity=10;     %Gravity's acceleration
    c_bounce=1;     %Bouncing's coefficient of elasticity
%Declaring animation timestep
    dt=0.0125;      %Animation timestep
%Drawing first frame
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Removed (commented) the first plot
% % %     ball=rectangle('Position',[-r_ball,initpos,r_ball,r_ball],...
% % %               'Curvature',[1,1],...
% % %               'FaceColor','b');
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
    line([-5*r_ball,5*r_ball],...
         [0,0]);
%Executing animation
    pos=initpos-r_ball;             %Ball's current vertical position
    vel=initvel;                    %Ball's current vertical velocity
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
    axis([-5*r_ball,5*r_ball,0,initpos+2*r_ball]);
        axis('equal');
        axis('off');
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
    while 1
        %Declaring time counter
        t_loopstart=tic();
        %Updating ball's condition
        pos=pos+(vel*dt);           %Ball's current vertical position
        vel=vel-(gravity*dt);       %Ball's current vertical velocity
        %Adjusting ball's velocity if the ball is hitting the floow
        if pos<0
            vel=-vel*c_bounce;      %Balls' current vertical velocity
        end
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Removed (commented) clearing figure, replaced by "delete" of ball at the
% end of the loop (delete of the "rectangle handle")
%Clearing figure
% % %         clf;
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
        %Drawing frame
        ball=rectangle('Position',[-r_ball,pos,r_ball,r_ball],...
                  'Curvature',[1,1],...
                  'FaceColor','b');
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Removed unnecessary plot instructions

% % %         line([-5*r_ball,5*r_ball],...
% % %              [0,0]);
        %Preserving axes
% % %         axis([-5*r_ball,5*r_ball,0,initpos+2*r_ball]);
% % %         axis('equal');
% % %         axis('off');
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
        %Pausing animation
        el_time=toc(t_loopstart);
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Removed (commented) display of Elapsed time (to speed up the script)
% % %         disp(['Elapse time : ',num2str(el_time),' seconds']);
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
        pause(dt-el_time);
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Inserted "delete(ball)" to remove the ball before next plot; this replace
% the "clf" instruction commneted above
        delete(ball)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
    end
%CodeEnd-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is incredible, changing the scale seems obvious now... Also I appreciate code optimisation. Thanks a lot.